# Drupalのターム構造を反映したURLをPathautoモジュールで実現させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？。

Tags: cms, drupal

下のようなボキャブラリ及びそのタームがあるとします。

---

◆ボキャブラリ
World（マシンネーム：world）

◆ターム
Japan（URLエイリアス：japan）
　└Osaka（URLエイリアス：japan/osaka）
　　　└Namba（URLエイリアス：japan/osaka/namba）

---

そして、Pathautoモジュールの機能を使い、NambaタームのページのURLを下のようにしたいと思っております。

http://example.com/world/japan/osaka/namba

要は、ボキャブラリのマシンネームをルートディレクトリとし、
その下は、そのボキャブラリに属するタームの階層構造をそのままURLに反映したいのです。

その場合、Pathautoの設定画面（/admin/config/search/path/patterns）にて、
どのように設定すればいいのでしょうか？
また、そのパターンは決め打ちではなく、汎用性を持たせるためにtokenという変数のようなものを使用したく思っております。

自分でも何種類のパターンを試したのですが上のようなパスにはなりませんでした。。
Drupalのバージョンは7.52です。

ご存知の方がおられましたらお教えいただけませんでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/70123

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12172125512